# Openssh home dir mods

Tags: linux, directory, sftp, openssh, account-restrictions

Our recently deceased guru compiled a version of openssh for Scientific Linux in 2012 that allows us to "lock" users into their home directories in a really cool way.

For example, we make their home dir (like) `/u/sftpdir/./username`.  When they login, all they see is `/username`.

If we modify that to `/u/sftpdir/username/./`, upon sftp login they only see `/`.  They cannot go 'up' the tree from there; effectively, the dot is root.

Now, I need to update our openssh, and I am not sure what he did to make that work.  We are not chrooting, and that would require way too much reconfiguration and many continual man-hours to convert to.  Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps like what is discussed in the top answer [here](http://superuser.com/questions/299036/can-i-create-an-ssh-user-which-can-access-only-certain-directory)?

Comment: Are these accounts restricted to SFTP? Or do they need more general ssh access?

Comment: currently we allow them ftp, ftps, sftp.  Migrating to sftp-only, but converting to chroot is not feasible.  we are using sftpsh for all accts.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he used the -d flag of the sftp-server?

This is the description from the man page:

-d start_directory
specifies an alternate starting directory for users. The pathname may contain the following tokens that are expanded at runtime: %% is replaced by a literal '%', %d is replaced by the home directory of the user being authenticated, and %u is replaced by the username of that user. The default is to use the user's home directory. This option is useful in conjunction with the sshd_config(5) ChrootDirectory option.

Although I'm not sure if this option can be used without a chroot.